# Spam responses from website contact form bypassing 'required' and 'pattern' attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, spam-prevention

I have a contact form on a website that has been receiving a lot of spam.  It is hosting on Github so my methods of server side validation / captcha is quite limited.  All fields always had the 'required' attribute and I have added some 'pattern' attributes to the form field and a very basic security question.

Originally I would receive spam responses with all fields completed but random numbers where the name should be, a name where the phone number should be, an email, and URLs in the message area.

When I first added just the security question handled by javascript / jquery, it seems to have no effect so I am assuming the bot could read the correct answer from the code??  What is more concerning, is that after more recently adding some 'pattern' attribute to the form fields I have started getting spam responses that still contain random numbers where the name should be, and now the phone and email field is non existent (not submitted / entered).

I do not get how the field can be submitted when it doesnt match the pattern validation, or how two fields can be left blank when they still have the 'required' attribute.  I have tested the form myself and all validation and required fields function as expected and all fields are received like they used to be so it is just the spammer that seems to ignore these rules.

If anyone can please explain what may be happening / have happened here??  Also / alternatively if anyone is aware of a better and proven way of weeding out spam responses that works with the form I have and within the constraints of hosting the website on Github that would be GREATLY appreciated!!

The website in question is http://orionimportgroup.com/ if you would like to see the form in the live environment.

```js
var n1 = Math.round(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
var n2 = Math.round(Math.random() * 10 + 1);

$('document').ready(function(){
 $("#a").val(n1 + " + " + n2);
 document.getElementsByName('captcha')[0].placeholder=("CAPTCHA CODE: " + n1 + "+" + n2);
});

$('form').submit(function(e) {
 if (eval($("#captcha").val()) == (parseInt(n1) + parseInt(n2))) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
   url: "https://docs.google.com/a/blakedavies.net/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfHdHMJePTJ3R5JOtBrH8zdPdX74eXQ8TDFIGjgkbIbGNdpnQ/formResponse",
   data: $(this).serialize(),
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "xml",
   success: function(data) {
    console.log('Submission successful');
   },
   error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log('Submission failed: ' + error);
   }
  });
  $('#gform *').fadeOut(0);
  $('#contact-box *').fadeOut(0);
  $('#gform').prepend(
   '<div class="thank-you-box"><p class="thank-you">Hi, thanks for reaching out! We will get back to you within 24 hours.</p><p class="thank-you">If your issue cannot wait, you can also reach us via our <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Orion-Import-Group-110501569627947/">Facebook Page</a> or call 0429-105-580.</p></div>'
  );
  return true;
 }
 else{
  alert('You have not entered the correct captcha code value');
  return false;
 }
});
```

```html
<form name="gform" id="gform" enctype="text/plain" action="https://docs.google.com/a/blakedavies.net/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfHdHMJePTJ3R5JOtBrH8zdPdX74eXQ8TDFIGjgkbIbGNdpnQ/formResponse">
  <div class="inner">
   <input name="entry.1683926249" id="entry.1683926249" placeholder="Name" required pattern="[A-Za-z' -]+" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid name using letters only.')" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" />
  <input name="entry.189066148" id="entry.189066148" placeholder="Phone" required pattern="[0-9 -]+" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid phone number using numbers only.')" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" />
  <input name="entry.429019481" id="entry.429019481" placeholder="Email" required pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,3}$" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid email making sure to include an @ sign and the domain suffix (.com .net etc.).')" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" />
 </div>
 <div class="inner">
  <textarea name="entry.2094840737" id="entry.2094840737" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
  <input name="captcha" id="captcha" placeholder="CAPTCHA CODE: 5+7" required />
 </div>
  <input class="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Message" />
</form>
<script src="js/contactform.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Technically there's nothing to stop a bot from inserting a new form on your page that goes to the same url that does none of your validation.  Also a quick glance at your script, `n1` and `n2` appear to be global variables so any script could access those to know what the captcha should equal.  It's also fairly trivial for a js script to remove the required property from dom elements.

Comment: `required` atribute works only in browsers (modern browsers). But, a bot isn't a browser - it can send you a request directly (without forms and html inputs..). So you should make a server-side validation because it's the only secure option for you. Front-end part doesn't matters much and can be broken easily almost always...

Comment: I would suggest potentially implementing a real captcha like google offers which will let you validate the captcha response server side to make sure the user passed the validation, rather than this custom one that is only client side.

Comment: Google recaptcha is maybe the best option for you. But if you say you can't do much on the server-side... then idk. Server-side protection is always better, because it is not accessible from client-side. A bot can simply manipulate his side, make a request however he wants. BUT when the request comes to the server there's nothing a bot could possibly do. So yeah. Just giving you an opened explanation :))

Comment: Can you afford $5 a month for a real server?  If not, you might want to remove the contact form because as mentioned above, bots and scripts do not run any of the script code that you add to the page.  They submit a POST directly using PHP's cURL or the equivalent for their bot language.  You need to be able to do validation on the server side to be able to filter spam.

Comment: @MaxMaximilian Yeah, I understand that server side is best, but this question is mainly directed at the fact that previous to the addition of the 'pattern' attribute in the HTML, all spam responses came with all fields filled (following the 'required' attribute).  The spam responses that come through now with some fields missing are practically identical to the old ones in terms of company and wording etc..  In addition to this, I just had a few come in with NO field filled (no information at all)... odd spam from a bot fi they send nothing??  Any ideas??

Comment: @Taplar Yeah I realised that the n1 and n1 could be read and inferred by a bot, but this question is mainly directed at the fact that previous to the addition of the 'pattern' attribute in the HTML, all spam responses came with all fields filled (following the 'required' attribute).  The spam responses that come through now with some fields missing are practically identical to the old ones in terms of company and wording etc..  In addition to this, I just had a few come in with NO field filled (no information at all)... odd spam from a bot fi they send nothing??  Any ideas??

Answer (score 6):

One way to prevent spam is **Honeypot technique**, it is proven to work and prevented more than 90% of spam for my company's site.

To implement the Honeypot technique, all that’s required is adding a hidden form field to the form.

And that’s what gives away whether the form submission is spam or not:
 **Real users** don’t see the hidden field so they won’t submit it with any value.
**Spam bots**, however, will still see the field in the form’s markup, auto-populate it with something, and submit it with the rest of the form.

So from there all that’s needed is to test whether the hidden field was submitted with a value or not.  If it was, the submission can be treated as spam.

Read more about [Honeypot technique](https://solutionfactor.net/blog/2014/02/01/honeypot-technique-fast-easy-spam-prevention/)

**Response to comments and additional info (I can't comment yet)**

@user7531422, try it like this:
Add a class to an additional input element **(honeypot element)** with CSS style to hide it `display: none;`, and make it look same as the name or phone field but change name attribute.
most bots will read only the HTML markup and won't notice CSS rules, and **most bots aren't so smart to dive into every piece of code**.

Before submitting the form directly check if your hidden field has data **(Check for it value if not empty)**, if so don't even send the form.
It's a client side solution.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was under the impression that as the validation would be in the code that the bot could read the field as hidden or read the validation rule and abide by it?? I need a solution that works browser side if possible as I cant host server side scripts on Github.

Comment: He's saying don't use `<input type="hidden"`, but use CSS. The CSS could also be bypassed but is another step. You could also try positioning it off-screen, but leave it visible.

Comment: @Nick Yeah thanks for clarifying... but as I cant use server side scripts, won't a bot be able to read my jquery validation (if field 'X' contains any input, dont submit form) and then treat it accordingly??  Or is there a way around that??

Comment: Can you just toss out results that include the fake field on the Google Forms end? Otherwise, yes, they could filter that out but it would require the bot creator to have to update their code.

Comment: @Nick looked into in and yeah there is a premium licence for the google form addon I'm using to send email notification for the form responses that gives me the capability to validate fields before sending the email notification.  This solution is basically the equivalent of server-side validation.  Costs $39 / year but that is cheaper than the hosting cost for my combined websites would cost so best I'm gonna get.  Thanks for your help!!  Would still love to know why the bots started acting so differently to my forms thought haha